# Add plugin on Django-CMS page programatically in unit test

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, plugins, django-cms

My Django app needs a test that follows the following scenario: creates a page, edits it by adding a new plugin, then saves it. So far, I am stuck at adding the plugin to the page. How can I do this programatically in a test?

I looked over `add_plugin()` from `cms.api`, but it needs a placeholder, which I have no idea how to link to an existing page and/or template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a page with cms.api... and then get the right placeholder form page.placeholders.all() and call the add_plugin() with this.

Comment: It appears that my test page doesn't have any placeholder associated, it returns `[]`. Where do I need to create them? And do I need to specify something in my test template?

Comment: Managed to solve this by manually creating some placeholders in my test template.